# Recover Chrome history

Tags: google-chrome, history

Today I reinstalled my computer and I want to recover my history from before the reinstallation. I logged into my Google account and I checked my history, but there I found history only from my phone.

Comment: By "preinstalled", do you actually mean "reinstalled"?

Comment: yes from window 7 to windows 7

Comment: Your browser history was on your computer, nowhere else [imagine the privacy concerns if it was anywhere else]. If you don't have a backup, it's gone.

Comment: ok, I have it backed up, can you just tell me where the path?

Comment: Chrome supports syncing history to another computer, but you have to manually configure it, and verify the sync has completed, before you wipe out the old computer.  It also supports exporting history to a csv file.  Google's own help says there is no way to import from that csv file....

Answer (score 1):

Google supports syncing data across multiple devices so long as you are logged into the same account.

[image]

If you already had your sync settings setup, and you don't have any Chrome extensions that alter your history, it should sync.

Comment: murloc wrote *I logged into my Google account and I checked my history, but there I found history only from my **phone**.* which leads to the question of how murloc  can recover his Chrome history under these conditions, specifically is there anywhere else in his Google account where murloc can find his Chrome history from his computer.